# Getline is reading strings as characters

Tags: c++, std, getline

I have a text file with one line of information structured as follows:

> Manufacturer ModelNumber    SerialNumber

I am trying to use getline to retrieve the information:

```
std::string vendorID;
std::ifstream vendFile;
vendFile.open(fNameVendID);
std::getline(vendFile, vendorID);
printf("Info: \t\t%s\n", vendorID);
```

The output to the console is:

> E2^

Am I missing something here with getline?  It looks like it is printing the three different "words" from the text file into three characters.

Comment: `%s` format specifier expects a `char*`, not a `std::string`. Your code exhibits undefined behavior. Make it `printf("Info: \t\t%s\n", vendorID.c_str());`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why use `printf` at all? After all it's a C++ program so outputting to `std::cout` should be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf %s` modifier expect a C-like `char*` string, not an `std::string`

```
printf("Info: \t\t%s\n", vendorID.c_str());
```

or just, in standard C++ , forget about `printf` :

```
std::cout << "Info: \t\t" << vendorID << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's either

```
std::cout << "Info:\t\t" << vendorID <<std::endl;
```

or

```
printf("Info: \t\t%s\n", vendorID.c_str());
```